# Merge the array duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => tirupur ) 
Array ( [0] => coimbatore ) 
Array ( [0] => coimbatore [1] => chennai ) 
Array ( [0] => coimbatore [1] => chennai [2] => madurai ) 
Array ( [0] => bangalore )
```

I want the final array to be like below output

```
Array ( [0] => tirupur [1]=>coimbatore [2]=>chennai [3]=>madurai [4]=>bangalore)
```

Comment: *I want the final array to be like below output* That's nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can combine first all array in to one array and then try to do like this way

```
<?php
$array1 = array("orange", "apple", "grape");
$array2 = array("peach", 88, "plumb");
$array3 = array("lemon", 342);
$newArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);

array_unique($newArray);
```

hope this will sure help you

Comment: $functional_results = $objMain->getResults("SELECT DISTINCT locations FROM tbl_jobs"); 
   foreach($functional_results as $res){
    $loc=explode("-",$res['locations']);
    print_r($loc); 
    echo '<br>';
   }   my array list are only in one array.. not different array list.. how can merge

Comment: @user853278 I have mention in my answer that use the `array_unique` function if you have one array.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing the following code snippet

```
  $a=array('tirupur');
  $b=array('coimbatore');
  $c=array('coimbatore','chennai');
  $d=array('coimbatore','chennai','madurai');
  $e=array('bangalore');
  $x=array_unique(array_merge($a,$b,$c,$d,$e));
  $result=array_values($x);
  print_r($result);
 ?>
```